Untangle the pairs!
This is a crossword puzzle, that contains only pairs. Unfortunately, the pairs became intermingled... To find out the pairs, the numbers in parenthesis give a small hint.
The final solution is 2 words that describe these pairs.




Across
Down




1. very steeply (1)
2. lack of warmth (3)


6. apologies (6)
3. more black than others (7)


8. blend (4)
4. powered by water, wind or movement (6)


10. a nut of a tree with the same name (4)
5. a series of links (6)


11. a shout of encouragement (7)
7. low seat (1)


12. accesible (4)
9. capsules of a cotton plant (6)


13. a Saoudi for example (3)
12. petty quarrels (1)


14. viper (1)
13. 12 o'clock (10)


16. playful (7)
14. hasten (6)


17. gem, could be white or black (4)
15. type of meat (10)


20. one foot before the other (4)
16. metal piece (6)


22. amphibian (3)
18. bread (8)


23. something that is done, could be good or bad (10)
19. big cat (4)


25. spirited horses (1)
21. two of a kind (8)


27. plural of #29 (1)
24. tooth of a snake (4)


28. looks like violet (7)
26. rude person (4)


29. do…while (10)
27. guy (3)





 Every clue answer must be shifted up or down by the number in parentheses to form another word, which is also clued in the crossword:


 


 Reading the blue letters down and the orange letters up, we see that these are ROTATING PAIRS.


Correct of course! Once you get the mechanism, the puzzle becomes a lot easier ;)
